# Cherry pick numbers from a paragraph only if there is a certain word on that line

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

From the following prose, I want to extract a list of numbers from any -line- that contains the letters "HTML". html could be upper case or lower case.

So here's the psuedo code:
text = getline()
if text contains html
   match any numbers from text
   return array of matches

Any ideas how to do this in REG Ex?

===============

```
HTML email is still … a great marketing tool if used properly. The key is to test, test,
 test to see if your subscribers prefer 5 it over text based email. If you are unsure your
 subscribers can read HTML email, then offer both text-based email and HTML 7 email, to 
cater to both audiences.

In my Part $254,000 of this article, I will discuss “How to create and send an HTML email 
form” to increase the interactivity of your subscribers and boost the response rate in your
 email marketing campaigns. retro 50's
```

=============

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if there is `html` in the string, then match all digits:

```
if (preg_match("/html/i", $input)) {
    preg_match_all("/\b(\d+)\b/", $input, $m);
}
print_r($m);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample solution:

```
$line=strtolower($line);
$x = preg_match("/html.*(\d+)/",$line,$match) || preg_match("/(\d+).*html/",$line,$match);
if($x)echo "number in line: ".$match[1];
```

Assumes only one number in line. Definitely not the best way to do it, but you really should learn regex yourself - it's not that hard.

See also http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: @Jason - regular-expressions.info is an excellent site, it has tutorials and full explanations for everything you'll need. The best way to learn is to build it yourself, either from scratch or by adapting a solution that doesn't quite do what you want into one that does.

Answer (score 0):

```
^((\d+)|.)*(HTML|html)((\d+)|.)*$
```

Getting the capture groups right might be a little tricky, but just mess around a little.